# Message Missing resource when deploy an application

Tags: cloudify

when i try to deploy my recipe i receive this message

"Missing resource in messages resource bundle: /tmp/application1057175116785725281.zip"

is there a limit for the zip file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please run "install-application --verbose .... and then write the output here and also attach log file if possible.

Thanks,
Tamir.